# How does Eve manage to do whatever on Earth?

Tags: lucifer

In S04 of *Lucifer* [Eve](https://lucifer.fandom.com/wiki/Eve) arrives to Earth.

She seems to be extremely well versed in how **contemporary** Earth works, despite being in Heaven since ever.

She mentions that she asked questions about life on Earth by people "going up" and realizing life on Earth is fun, but this is not enough to understand how to deal with our world (she knows about planes, about the post office, teeth brushes, how to order in a bar (where does she have money from?), etc.

**How does she manage to get by?**

Comment: I've only watched the odd episode whilst my wife has it on but isn't the implication that she learnt what she could from Heaven and then Lucifer helps her out greatly but beyond that she is unbelievably naïve about most things.

Comment: So..... why is it "not enough to understand"?  That seems like a somewhat arbitrary personal assessment by you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Episode 5 of Season 4](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8565626/?ref_=tt_ch), Eve mentions that Heaven has ESPN

> Adam's idea of paradise was laying around all day doing nothing. Once we got ESPN up there, forget it.

The implication is that Heaven apparently has television. They never go deeper in to this, but one would assume that Heaven also has other shows. Eve seemed to have an infatuation with Earth so she most likely studied Earth through TV shows before coming down.

Comment: This is a good finding, I missed that. If on top of TV they have fiber then she would indeed be ready.

Answer (score 2):

Eve has been chatting with every soul she could as they entered the pearly gates. She learned enough to get by, and has been soaking herself in current Earth culture since arriving. Her absolute love for Earth allows her to rapidly fit in. This is the opposite of the problems faced by Lucifer's mother, as she had nothing but disdain for Earth. She's also beautiful, and used that to get ahead in certain situations, like hitching a plane ride to California.